# Carga sencilla ajax funciona en Firefox peron no funciona en Chrome

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy intentado un ejemplo en Ajax que al parecer solo funciona en Firefox. En Chrome no funciona. ¿Alguien sabe porque? Gracias

index.html

```
  <div class="contenedor">
        <p>AJAX</p>          
        <button id="cargar" value="cargar">Cargar</button>
        <div id="contenido"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/06.js"></script>
```

06.js

```
var btnCargar = document.getElementById('cargar');

function cargarContenido() {
  // se crea
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // se abre
   xhr.open("GET", "servidor.php", true);

   // revisar que cambie
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      console.log(xhr.readyState);

      if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
          //console.log("Se cargo correctamente");
          var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

          //console.log(json);
          var contenido = document.getElementById('contenido');
          contenido.innerHTML = json.frontend;
      } 
   };
   xhr.send(); 
}

btnCargar.addEventListener('click', cargarContenido );
```

servidor.php

```
$tecnologias = array(
    'frontend' => 'html5, css3, javascript',
    'backend' => 'php, mysql, apache',
    'fullstack' => 'html, css3, javascript, php, mysql, apache'
);
echo json_encode($tecnologias);
```

Comment: lo que sucede es que estas usando javascript puro, prueba con un fw como jQuery por medio de sus ajax para evitarte problemas con diferentes navegadores. revisa la sig. URL: https://cursos.mejorcodigo.net/article/jquery-metodos-de-ajax-get-y-post-11

Comment: te dejo una pequeña guia: https://fernando-gaitan.com.ar/ajax-facil-primera-parte/

Comment: doc oficial ajax : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Hasta que parte funciona?, logras instanciar el objeto ajax?, algún "console.log" imprimio algo?, hay algún error que te muestre en consola?

Comment: usas jQuery o tiene q ser js puro?

Comment: Es muy raro que en chrome no funcione. He encontrado esta  [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557247/easiest-way-to-retrieve-cross-browser-xmlhttprequest) en ingles para que ajax funcione en todos los navegadores. Luego, mirate [w3schools ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557247/easiest-way-to-retrieve-cross-browser-xmlhttprequest) ya que todo el mundo te envia informacion sobre jQuery.

Comment: También estaría muy bien que explicaras si el error es en el envío o en la respuesta. Que llega al php y que devuelve

Comment: A ver muchachos la solución no es utiluzar jQuery para hacer una petición... Vas a cargar una libreria entera para ello ?? Mirate la nueva forma de hacer peticiones: Fetch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: En el devtools, F12 en el navegador en la pestaña console y network que error da ? 404?500?

Answer (score 0):

> intenta con este codigo JS y me comentas, donde puede variar en vez de hacer console.log manipulas el HTML una vez tengas la respuesta que necesitas

```
    let myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");


let requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
};

fetch("http://localhost/servidor.php", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema se puede solucionar haciendo que el código se ejecute una vez se haya cargado toda la página.

Por ejemplo:

```js
window.onload = () => {
    var btnCargar = document.getElementById('cargar');

    function cargarContenido() {
    // se crea
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // se abre
    xhr.open("GET", "servidor.php", true);

    // revisar que cambie
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(xhr.readyState);

        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            //console.log("Se cargo correctamente");
            var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            //console.log(json);
            var contenido = document.getElementById('contenido');
            contenido.innerHTML = json.frontend;
        } 
    };
    xhr.send(); 
    }

    btnCargar.addEventListener('click', cargarContenido );
}
```

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta de la fecha de esta consulta, jejeje. Sorry!